# Eclipse Helios Android emulator how to run sample project

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi I have installed eclipse helios with android emulation like its written 
http://www.futuredesktop.org/developing_android_apps_on_ubuntu.html but after running application

```
package com.example.android.apis;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ApiDemos extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

I only see this screen 
[image] How can I run this simple project ??

Edit: Problem was that package name was always this same, when I changed it, it works fine.

Comment: Thats the emulator. Just try running the app again, either click run or press `Ctrl+F11` inside eclipse. If an emulator is already running, your app will get uploaded to it, so keep it open.

Comment: `[2011-08-30 13:30:44 - test] Uploading test.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-08-30 13:30:44 - test] Installing test.apk...
[2011-08-30 13:30:46 - test] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2011-08-30 13:30:46 - test] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2011-08-30 13:30:46 - test] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.example.android.apis' in a shell.
[2011-08-30 13:30:46 - test] Launch canceled!` this is what I got

Comment: You are trying to install your apk over an existing apk. You have to either uninstall the existing app first or create a new project with a new package name.

Comment: Right, you're trying to install the API-samples project, which comes preinstalled on every emulator. Either perform `adb uninstall com.example.android.apis` in a command line or uninstall these from the android settings in the emulator. But I strongly recommend creating a new project to test things out. Thats way easier and you still have untouched samples to look at later.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after you posted what your eclipse is saying there are two routes you can take, either make a new project or uninstall the existing. I will cover both.

Uninstalling:
Exactly what it says. Open up a terminal. If you are on windows do

`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb uninstall com.example.android.apis` As needed (either because you installed it elsewhere or you are on Linux/Mac), substitute C:\Program File\Android for the Android home folder. You should know where it is since you declared it. If you are unsure, in Eclipse do `Window -> Preferences -> Android` and look at where the android sdk is.

Making a new project:

In eclipse `File -> New -> Android Project`. Follow the steps to creating a new android project. There are two things you want to note here: the **Create Activity** and **Package name**. Your package name something like `com.example` for now (or whatever you want it to be). It should not be the same as `com.example.android.apis`. Then just copy and paste the above code into your new Android class. You might need to change the class name from `ApiDemos` to your new **Activity** name.

Comment: im on ubuntu but I have tried `adb uninstall com.example.android.apis` in `android-sdk-linuks/tools` folder but i recive message that `adb` is not recognized. I have also tryied make a new project but still I got this message which I have post in my 1 post

Comment: `/platform-tools` not `/tools`

Comment: Still `adb` is not recognized, after `root@skworonline:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools# adb uninstall com.example.android.apis
`

Comment: You shouldn't have `# `. It should look like this `root@skworonline:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/adb uninstall com.example.android.apis`

Comment: It is automaticly added. But problem is that `adb` is not recognized

Comment: if you do an `ls /usr/local/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/` is adb in that folder?

Comment: Also: are you sure that it isn't `/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: `adb` is in this folder but its a file

Comment: @skowron-line let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2989/discussion-between-otra-and-skowron-line)

Comment: If you want to run a executable from the current working directory instead of the PATH on unix/linux, use `./` as a prefix. So in this case `./adb uninstall ...`

Answer (score 1):

in the **Package Explorer**, right click on **project folder** and select **Run As**

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't start the app but the emulator only, by using the menu "Windows/Android and SDK manager/start [applied to a virtual device]" of Eclipse.

When you start your app, the console output of Eclipse shoud be saying (replace `00-sandbox` by the name of your app):

```
[2011-08-30 13:26:16 - 00-sandbox] Uploading 00-sandbox.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-08-30 13:26:16 - 00-sandbox] Installing 00-sandbox.apk...
[2011-08-30 13:26:19 - 00-sandbox] Success!
[2011-08-30 13:26:19 - 00-sandbox] Starting activity org.shlublu.android.sandbox.Main on device emulator-5554
[2011-08-30 13:26:22 - 00-sandbox] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.shlublu.android.sandbox/.Main }
```

If this is not the case, this means the app was not uploaded or not started on the emulator, or neither of them. You must then press "ctrl+f11" to run the application. Eclipse will ask you whether this is an Android app, a Java app or anything else: chose "Android Application".